# Multithreading inside for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to read the multiple files from a directory and create a separate thread for every file.While iterating the loop, the anonymous inner class cannot use non final variables.

My question is how to create multiple threads inside a loop.(I am required to manually create threads for each file, cant use executor service or something else)

```
class de
{

    void commit(File x){

       int sum =0;
       try{
           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(x);
           byte[]b= new byte[5000];
           fin.read(b);
           for (byte digit:b){
               sum=digit+sum;
           }
           System.out.println(sum);
       }
       catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){    
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Sanjana\\workspace\\IO\\Numbers");
        File []store = f.listFiles( new FilenameFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File f, String name){
                return name.endsWith("txt");
            }
        });

       for (File x: store){   
           Thread t = new Thread(){
               public void run (){
               //new de().commit(x); /**/Error here non final variable x**
               }
           };
       }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing your posted code!

Comment: Are you sure reading those files from several threads will improve application performance? Please keep in mind that your hard disk cannot have its reading head at different positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for (File x: store)
```

to

```
for (final File x: store)
```

---

**Edit** you state:

> Its working but final variables are constant, here x is changing to each element of store.howz that working

`x` is a parameter of the for-each loop and can be declared final as per the definition of for-each loop. Each time the loop loops, it's as if x is created anew.

---

Per the [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) section on the enhanced for loop:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

So this tells me that final would fit in like so:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    final VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

So the `x` is really the Identifier above and is in actuality re-declared with each iteration of the loop.

In your code, I'm thinking that it's equivalent to:

```
  for (Iterator<File> iterator = Arrays.asList(scores).iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     final File file = iterator.next();
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           new de().commit(file);
        }
     }).start();  
  }
```

---

**Edit 2**
Note that your use of Thread can be improved, that you should get in the habit of using a Runnable:

```
   for (final File x: store){   
       new Thread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
           new de().commit(x);  // "de" should be "De" since it is a class
         }
       }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Its working but final variables are constant, here x is changing to each element of store.howz that working

Comment: @Sanjana: please see **Edit 2** to answer.